# JAVASCRIPT - "Code inside event" timeout? o.O

Tags: javascript, events, timeout

I have this event inside my page

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function(){
            var load_screen = document.getElementById("load_screen");
            document.getElementsByTagName("BODY")[0].setAttribute("class", "loaded");
            })
```

wich adds an attribute for the body `class="loaded"` when the page is loaded but because of I added a cool preloader effect I'd like to make the event wait 3-5 seconds before showing the real page, even if it is already fully loaded (But of course wait even more if not fully loaded).
Is this possible in some way?

Comment: Inside the event callback trigger `setTimeout()` and put your code in its callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you want is for the delay to be a *minimum* of 5 seconds, you can capture the time at the point you establish the event handler (i.e., well before the "load" event has fired), and then check the time again in the handler.

```
var startTime = Date.now();
window.addEventListener("load", function(){
  var load_screen = document.getElementById("load_screen");
  setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementsByTagName("BODY")[0].setAttribute("class", "loaded");
  }, Math.max(0, 5000 - (Date.now() - startTime)));
});
```

Also there's no reason to use `.setAttribute()` to set the class:

```
    document.getElementsByTagName("BODY")[0].className = "loaded";
```

Personally I'd either use the `.classList` facility or go old-school and add the new class:

```
    document.getElementsByTagName("BODY")[0].className += " loaded";
```

That way you don't step on any other classes that may be (possibly in the future) on the `<body>`.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the set attribute in a setTimeout function to execute after a set amount of time.

```
window.addEventListener("load", function(){
                   var load_screen = document.getElementById("load_screen");
                   setTimeout(function(){document.getElementsByTagName("BODY")[0].setAttribute("class", "loaded");}, 3000);
                })
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `window.setTimeout`

```
window.addEventListener("load", function(){
           window.setTimeout(
              function() {
                 var load_screen = document.getElementById("load_screen");
                 document.getElementsByTagName("BODY")[0].setAttribute("class", "loaded"); 
               },
               3000);
        })
```